# How to order rows by columns at arbitrary order ? MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query : 
$query = "SELECT * FROM table1 ONE ORDER BY ....:

the order should be in this way :

1. first the mysql should get the rows with status 2.
2. then get the row with status 1.
3. then get the row with status 3.

**status is a col at table1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [FIELD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function like this

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM table1 ONE ORDER BY FIELD(status, 2, 1, 3)";
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use conditionals in the `order by`.  Here is one method:

```
order by field(status, 2, 1, 3)
```